# Filter rows by timestamp in DataFrame of SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I want to filter rows of `DataFrame` in SparkR by time stamp with format like the following:

```
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                                             Timestamp=c('08/01/2014 11:18:30',
                                                         '01/01/2015 12:13:45',
                                                         '05/01/2015 14:17:33')))
```

Please note that original schema for `TimeStamp` column is `String`. Say I want to filter those time stamp before `03/01/2015 00:00:00`, I think there might be two approaches to do this:

One is to mutate the column to `timestamp` like normal R with `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Timestamp = mdy_hms(Timestamp)) %>%
 filter(Timestamp < mdy_hms('03/01/2015 00:00:00'))
```

But I failed to mutate columns of `DataFrame` since it's a S4 class `Column` not a vector.

Second approach might be to register the `DataFrame` as a table and then use `SparkSQL` to deal with `timestamp` type:

```
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                                             Timestamp=c('08/01/2014 11:18:30',
                                                         '01/01/2015 12:13:45',
                                                         '05/01/2015 14:17:33')))
registerTempTable(df, 'df')
head(sql(sqlContext, 'SELECT * FROM df WHERE Timestamp < "03/01/2015 00:00:00"'))
```

But since it's still a string comparison so it would give wrong result. What would be correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spark 1.6+**

You should be able to use `unix_timestamp` function and standard `SQLContext`:

```
ts <- unix_timestamp(df$Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') %>%
  cast("timestamp")

df %>% 
   where(ts <  cast(lit("2015-03-01 00:00:00"), "timestamp"))
```

**Spark < 1.**

This should do the trick:

```
sqlContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)

query <- "SELECT * FROM df
    WHERE unix_timestamp(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') < 
          unix_timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00')" # yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, ...)
registerTempTable(df, 'df')

head(sql(sqlContext, query))

##   ID           Timestamp
## 1  1 08/01/2014 11:18:30
## 2  2 01/01/2015 12:13:45
```

Please note that the choice of the context is important here. Since `unix_timestamp` is a Hive UDF standard `SQLContext` you get by default in SparkR won't work here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question, if I want to change the schema from `string` to `timestamp`, how can I do it in `SparkR`? I tried `query <- "SELECT ID, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) ts from df"
newDf <- sql(sqlContext, query)
newDf$ts <- cast(newDf$ts, "timestamp")
head(newDf)` but it has error `cannot coerce class ""jobj"" to a data.frame`

Comment: As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with your query (although you can simply use this `"SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP(unix_timestamp(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) ts FROM df"`). It looks like that required conversion is simply not implemented in SparkR.